# Why does Google intentionally disable features in most countries?

Tags: android-wear, google-pay

Why does Google intentionally disable features in most countries? Prime example being, Google Pay for Wear OS.

**Background:** Google Pay actually works just fine in most countries as far as I can tell, but with the Oreo update the app is constantly being disabled. If you enable it, it still continues to function as per normal.

**Question:** What benefits do Google get for locking this down in countries other than their selected handful?

Comment: Legal reasons I'm sure.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Do you know what legalities are limiting them here? Wouldn't the fact that it still works for short periods of time mean they are still violating any legal restrictions?